# What is the best way to implement of facebook like wall application in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say you have a social network with 500,000 to 1,000,000 users and want to have each user see a unique set of data that is related to them.  Obviously if you have a lot of simultaneous users, this is going to be a huge hit in terms of performance for DB queries.  What is the best way to implement something like this, in general terms, knowing that the underlying data (through updates, or deletes, or whatever) is likely to change often?

Comment: "best way to implement something like this, in general terms" by writing code.

Comment: like everything else, throw more hardware at it.

Comment: Design it to be scalable, and like Marc B said you can just keep adding hardware with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the database queries go, it's not a problem if you write the queries correctly and index your tables. When you go about writing a program that you suspect may have high volume of usage, don't worry about the performance of it right away. First make it work, then worry about how efficient it is after you actually use it. If it seems slow, you have to profile the code and determine what is taking the most time. After that, you can optimize the part you find, figuring out ways to accomplish the same thing in less time.

Answer (score 1):

Set up caching and when you reach a plateau, get more hardware.

**For simplifying Javascript-related tasks, reducing bandwidth via asynchronous requests and MySQL access:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

**Caching your PHP:**

http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php